# 403 - Insufficient Permission only on accountSummaries call

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm getting rejected only on the `accountSummaries/list` management call, everything else works fine - heck, it works even when executing it from the [reference page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list)! I double checked that the account being used was correct and, as I said, I have no issues performing the simple `accounts/list` call.

I'm using the python library, and for both of those calls no parameters are needed (so the chance of some embarrassing error are very low).

Basically I'm simply getting the service client and performing the simplest possible call:

```
 a = client.AnalyticsManagementClient()  # super simple wrapper
 a._service.management().accounts().list().execute()
 a._service.management().accountSummaries().list().execute()
```

The first call works fine, the second one returns a 403 error. Anyone have an idea why that might happen?

Full error is `HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just a scope issue: `accounts` needs at least one among

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly
```

while `accountSummaries` allows only the last two; it seems to be the only one that does not work with the `analytics` scope, which is the one our client was requesting.